Control the estimation error measured by induced matrix $L_1$ norm
when I use the lasso-type method to estimate a matrix, such as $A$, column by column, I observe that in the numerical experiments the estimation error $\|\hat{A}-A\|_{L_1}=\underset{1\le j \le p}{\max}|\hat{a}_{\cdot j}-a_{\cdot j}|_1$ seems to be bounded by $cM_p$ where $\|A\|_{L_1}=M_p$ and c is a constant.
I'm not sure whether this observation is correct or not. I know that $\|\hat{A}-A\|_{L_1}$ could be bounded by $s\|\hat{A}-A\|_{\max}$ where $s $ denotes the number of the nonzero elements in a column, but the results in numerical experiments seem to be different.
Is that correct?

Please explain what "the lasso-type method" is.  If it's any method that includes the zero matrix among the possibilities, then your result is (trivially) true with $c=1.$
